# Entering parameters for function without parentheses

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt and I am currently trying to connect a button press on a gui to a static function. The function in Qt to do this has the syntax of

```
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, someFunction);
```

So my code looks like

```
QObject::connect(w.doneButton,&QPushButton::on_doneButton_pressed,getList);
```

the problem is that getList needs input parameters

```
QList<DeviceWidget*>* getList(Window w)
{
    return w.getList();
}
```

If I replace getList with getList(w) I get a response saying that it cannot handle the () operator.

```
'operator()' is not a member of 'QList<DeviceWidget*>*' return connect_functor(sender,signal,context,slot,&Func2::operator(),type);}
```

There must be way to get around this. The Qt designers would not have put in a restriction like that, but I have been searching the internet for a few days and I can't seem to find anything.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to look at `std::bind` or `boost::bind()` to help with parameter binding..

Comment: 'operator()' is not a member of 'QList<DeviceWidget*>*' return connect_functor(sender,signal,context,slot,&Func2::operator(),type);}

Comment: *(Please forget my last comment, I read your code wrong.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(What I feel is) the idiomatic way to solve your problem would be by using `boost::bind()` or `std::bind()` (if you're using c++11), as suggested by @Nim in the comments.

For example:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
QObject::connect(w.doneButton, &QPushButton::on_doneButton_pressed, boost::bind(getList, w));

#include <functional>
QObject::connect(w.doneButton, &QPushButton::on_doneButton_pressed, std::bind(getList, w));
```

In c++11 you could also use a lambda function (although `bind` is more suitable for binding parameters):

```
QObject::connect(w.doneButton, &QPushButton::on_doneButton_pressed, [w]{ getList(w); });
```

If you can use neither c++11 nor Boost, you can fall back to a functor (this is a bit messier and basically what lambda does for you in c++11):

```
class getListProxy
{
public:
    getListProxy(Window w) : m_w(w) {}

    QList<DeviceWidget*>* operator()() {
        return getList(m_w);
    }

private:
    Window m_w;
};

QObject::connect(w.doneButton, &QPushButton::on_doneButton_pressed, getListProxy(w));
```

Also note that all these constructs will pass `w` by value, because `getList(Window w)` takes `w` by value. Depending on `Window`'s implementation, this may not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you. This was very comprehensive! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Connect the push button on_doneButton_pressed to another slot function and then call getList from within that slot function. That way, you can pass the window to getList.

```
QObject::connect (w.doneButton, &QPushButton::on_doneButton_pressed, &someFunction);

void Window::someFunction()
{
    getList(this);
}
```